# Click on a filename to open in a new tab with Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Often in my personal readme.txt files / log files, I have some references to other .txt files. It can be relative path (`..\notes\blah.txt`) or absolute path (like on the screenshot below).

Is it possible, for a .txt file, to have this behaviour in Sublime: **double-click on a filename to open it in a new tab?**

[image]

Comment: Good question! I've not tried it, but [Clickable URLs Plugin](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/ClickableUrls_SublimeText) might be helpful. You can set the default browser within it's settings, I wonder what would happen if you set the browser to Sublime... worth a try I guess

Comment: @DarrenH as its name implies, Clickable URLs allows ***URLs*** to be opened in a user-defined program, not random paths. Please actually research things before proposing them as a solution.

Comment: @MattDMo no research is required to see that this is designed to open URLs, as you correctly state, it's in the name. But it's perfectly plausible that it may be capable of opening local files as a side-effect and that is definitely worth exploring. I don't know if it would definitely work or not which is why I suggested it as a research direction and not an actual answer.

Comment: This can be done easily by a plugin. Any objection in doing that? I guess this should take around 20 lines of code to do what you want.

Comment: @Basj 1. add mouse click mapping in specific context 2. add command executed upon mouse event 3. parse line for file 4. sub process to open file/use st to open it in new window, panel etc

Comment: I also wish for such a plugin. for me it's fine even if the link has to be inside brackets

Comment: @Happy I found a solution, see answer. Hope it will be helpful for you too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: [Clickable URLs plugin](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/ClickableUrls_SublimeText) is not really usable for me, because it parses the whole file, highlights the URLs (thanks to a nice regex), and then listens to CTRL+ALT+ENTER: if more than ~ 500 highlighted items, Sublime Text becomes highly unresponsive.*

---

Here is a working solution.

1. First put this file `lllaunch.py` in your user packages (e.g. `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\`):

   ```
   import sublime, sublime_plugin
   import subprocess
   import webbrowser
   import re

   BROWSER = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
   EDITOR = 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe'

   class LllaunchCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           for region in self.view.sel():
               s = self.view.substr(self.view.line(region))
               i = region.begin() - self.view.line(region).begin()

               start = 0
               end = -1
               for j, c in enumerate(s):
                   if c == ' ':
                       if j < i:
                           start = j
                       else:
                           end = j
                           break
               word = s[start:end].strip() if end != -1 else s[start:].strip()
               isurl = bool(re.match("\\bhttps?://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;']*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_(|]", word))
               if isurl:
                   webbrowser.register('mybrowser', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(BROWSER))
                   webbrowser.get('mybrowser').open(word)
               else:
                   s = '"' + s.split('"')[s[:i].count('"')] + '"'

                   command = '"%s" %s' % (EDITOR, s)
                   subprocess.Popen(command)
   ```
2. Then add the following line to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`:

   ```
   { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+enter"], "command": "lllaunch" }
   ```
3. Restart Sublime Text.
4. Now:

   - doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> on an URL will open browser.
   - doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> on a filename with quotes (e.g. `"C:\test\readme.txt"`) will edit the file in your favorite editor.